# how to build mingw project statically

Tags: mingw, static-linking

I am creating a project on mingw under windows, with the --static key. But for some reason the bass.dll and opencv 4.5.2 libraries don't want to be linked statically. How can I build the entire project statically? this is how i build project in vscode:

```
        "--static",
        "-municode",
        "-mwindows",
        "-g",
        "main.cpp",
        "window-engine/Pixel.cpp",
        "resources.o",
        "videoPlayer/engine/videoEngine.cpp",
        "videoPlayer/video.cpp",
        "data/data.cpp",
        "-Lmingw/bin",
        "-Iinclude",
        "-L.",
        "-I.",
        "-l:libopencv_calib3d452.dll",
        "-l:libopencv_core452.dll",
        "-l:libopencv_dnn452.dll",
        "-l:libopencv_features2d452.dll",
        "-l:libopencv_flann452.dll",
        "-l:libopencv_gapi452.dll",
        "-l:libopencv_highgui452.dll",
        "-l:libopencv_imgcodecs452.dll",
        "-l:libopencv_imgproc452.dll",
        "-l:libopencv_ml452.dll",
        "-l:libopencv_objdetect452.dll",
        "-l:libopencv_photo452.dll",
        "-l:libopencv_stitching452.dll",
        "-l:libopencv_video452.dll",
        "-l:libopencv_videoio452.dll",
        "-l:bass.dll",
        "-lMsimg32",
        "-lWindowscodecs",
        "-lOle32",
        "-lD2d1",
        "-lws2_32 ",
        "-lCrypt32 ",
        "-lWldap32 ",
        "-lNormaliz",
        "-lWininet",
        "-std=c++17",
        "-o",
        "run.exe"
```

Comment: Doesn't make much sense to me... Why would you specify `--static` and then use `-l` flags to specify shared libraries (`.dll`) to link with?

Comment: is it possible to link the dll in another way? in the sense without -l. I don't have static versions of bass and opencv.

Comment: You have shared libraries, but you want to link statically? Still doesn't make much sense. But on Windows you can mix the 2 and link with some libraries as static and others as shared.

Comment: I need the program to be 1 exe. Is it possible to compile the project so that it is not necessary to store the dll along with the program

Comment: For that you need a static build and that requires having static libraries of all dependencies.